# Silverstripe could not update record

Tags: silverstripe

I have following code in Silverstripe

```
<?php

$product= Product::get()->filter("ProductCode", $UniqueCode)->First();
if($product){
  $product->Stock = "250";
  $product->Name = "Abcd 123";
  $product->write();
  echo "New Stock = ".$product->Stock; //this prints the OLD value not the NEW one. Nor database is updated.
}
?>
```

**Update:**
If I do `$product->Name = "Abcd 123";`, the `Name' field is getting updated, but not the`Stock`

This didn't work. The `Stock` field of `Product` table is not updated. Can anybody tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: pleas provide more details - place a `debug::dump($product);` or even `debug::show($UniqueCode);` into your code to analyze.

Comment: You're completly sure you get a $product from the query? Try a `var_dump($product)` or `echo $product->ID` after the query, or use a proper tool like xdebug to debug your code.

Comment: @wmk, yes  the `$product` returns the record

Comment: @munomono, `$product` returns the record

Comment: you should enable error logging... if you're in the if clause and the write fails, it'll throw an error. Maybe validation fails for this specific dataobject or some other weird error we cannot guess. Did i mention xdebug? A bit complicated to setup the first time (depending on your IDE), but you can step through your programm and see what's going on.

Comment: @wmk, can you check my update once

Comment: Stock is a Int or a Varchar? Or how does your Model look?

Comment: @munomono, actually I was sending String value to Integer field, `Stock` is integer field. I have fixed this issue, thanks

Comment: @WatsMyName glad to hear it's solved for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem. For someone who step up this thread with same issue in future.

Actually `Stock` field is integer and i was supplying string value. You need to convert string into integer before supplying to object. For example:

```
$updatedvalue = "250";
$updatedvalue = (int)$updatedvalue;
```

Comment: You should be able to simplify this by simply doing: `$updatedvalue = (int)"250";`

Comment: @Morven, i just gave that as an example, otherwise `$updatedvalue' comes from form field.